# Rails ActiveModel designing belongs_to and has_many with single class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-and-belongs-to-many, activemodel, ruby-on-rails-6

I need some help modeling my models and controller. Here is what I want to achieve:

I want to have a devise user named User (as usual) and a second model named Project. A Project should belong to a single User and at the same time should have many participants. The participants in a project should also be users (with devise registration/login) but the user, that created the project should not be able to participate.
So far, so good. Here comes the tricky part: In my controller I want to be able to write:

```
def participate
  p = Project.find(id: params[:id])
  p.participants << current_user unless p.participants.includes?(current_user) && !p.user_id.equal(current_user.id)
  if p.save
    redirect_back
  else
    render :project
  end
end
```

This doesn't work because p.participants is not an array and the query (I tried it in rails console) does not check my n:m table.
Here is my current model setup:

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  before_validation :set_uuid, on: :create
  validates :id, presence: true

  belongs_to :user
  has_and_belongs_to_many :participants, class_name: "User"
end
```

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  before_validation :set_uuid, on: :create
  validates :id, presence: true

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

  has_and_belongs_to_many :projects
end
```

Finally my migrations:

```
class CreateProjects < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :projects, id: false do |t|
      t.string :id, limit: 36, primary_key: true
      t.string :title
      t.belongs_to :user, index: true, foreign_key: true, type: :uuid
      t.datetime :published_at

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

```
class CreateJoinTableProjectsUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_join_table :users, :projects do |t|
      t.index :project_id
      t.index :user_id
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: just in case: one point is that I don't use default IDs in my models but uuids. for that I needed to change my migration to `create_join_table(:users, :projects, column_options: {type: :uuid})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to use has_many: through instead of has_and_belongs_to_many. This allows you to write cleaner code for validation.

1. Remove has_and_belongs_to_many from User and Project models
2. Add has_many :through to User and Project models

   ```
   rails g model UserProject user:references project:references
   rails db:migrate

   class User < ApplicationRecord
     ..
     has_many :user_projects
     has_many :projects, through: :user_projects
     ..
   end

   class Project < ApplicationRecord
     ..
     has_many :user_projects
     has_many :participants, through: :user_projects, source: 'user'
     ..
   end

   class UserProject < ApplicationRecord
     belongs_to :user
     belongs_to :project
   end
   ```
3. Add validation to UserProject model

   ```
   class UserProject < ApplicationRecord
     belongs_to :user
     belongs_to :project

     validate :check_participant

     private
     def check_participant
       return if project.participants.pluck(:id).exclude?(user.id) && project.user != user
       errors.add(:base, 'You cannot be participant')
     end
   end
   ```
4. Update participate method

   ```
   def participate
     p = Project.find(id: params[:id])
     begin
       p.participants << current_user
       redirect_back
     rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => invalid
       puts invalid.record.errors
       render :project
     end
   end
   ```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but I get an error that `project` an `user` are undefined in the validation method in the model. I replaced `project` with `self` and user should be devise's `current_user` which is not available inside of Model classses

Comment: @nurbs999 It's working. I trried it in my local. You're probably making a mistake somewhere. I can help if you share your current models and schema file.

Comment: Oh, ok. May I invite you to my git repo?

Comment: @nurbs999 sure, you can invite

Comment: I almost got it working but I get an InvalidRecord error in my controller if I try to participate in my own project. The ternary redirect is not working.

Comment: ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid in ProjectsController#participate